# Can I copy the pi1b system to pi2b?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a Raspberry Pi 1b, AMD recently bought a Pi2b. So I wonder if I can use image tools to copy pi1system to pi2? I may copy pi1's SD card to a `.img` file, then use the file  to create the data of pi2's micro SD card.

I knew that the CPU of both Pis are different. So *is that available*? Did someone tried?

If so, *will there be some hidden bugs* inside the system which we can't find immediately but affect the system work properly?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes you can, make sure your OS has an ARMv7 kernel.

### Long Answer

#### Some quotes from the [official Raspberry Pi blog](http://www.raspberrypi.org/raspberry-pi-2-on-sale/):

> Broadcom were willing to step up with a new SoC, BCM2836. This retains all the  features of BCM2835, but replaces the single 700MHz ARM11 with a 900MHz quad-core ARM Cortex-A7 complex: everything else remains the same, so there is no painful transition or reduction in stability.

Note: ARMv7 is backwards compatible with ARMv6, the quote below proves it.

> At launch, we are using the same ARMv6 Raspbian userland on both Raspberry Pi 1 and 2

#### There could be some hidden issues

It won't be caused by upgrading from Pi 1 model B to Pi 2 model B. It will be caused from copying the image. If you or your system hardcoded your network interface's MAC address it could potentially cause a problem. I know it's not the best example, but sometime people don't think and hardcode things that can change. It all depends on your OS.

#### Short how-to for installing the new kernel on raspbian

It's good idea to backup your SD card before making these changes, if something goes wrong it could prevent your Pi from booting.

To backup your SD card on Linux/OS X you can use (remember to select the correct device (sda/sdb/sdc):

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdX of=raspbian.img
```

To install ARMv7 kernel:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-rpi2-rpfv
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-rpi2-rpfv
```

Check /boot to make sure you've got kernel7.img:

```
ls -lsa /boot
```

Result of ls:

```
3861 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3953492 Feb 24 20:55 kernel.img
3818 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3908696 Feb 24 20:55 kernel7.img
```

If that does not work you can try forcing the kernel name by modifying your /boot/config.txt see http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Boot for more options.

#### Other Issues

Kernel modules like wifi drivers or streaming cam in this case can also cause problems on your new ARMv7 kernel if it is not supported by default see  http://l0l.org.uk/2015/02/headaches-whilst-upgrading-to-raspberry-pi-2/

Comment: Thx very much! I am using Raspbian, so does this OS have some hidden issues?

Comment: In my situation I have to force the kernel name. In "/boot/config.txt", add a line of `kernel=kernel7.img`.